# Eclipse BIRT Tomcat 7.041

Tags: birt

i've deployed birt.war on my tomcat 7.0.41.  Used manager app to verify that the war file was deployed correctly.  if i click on birt path, i get HTTP status 404 - /birt/ error.  it says the requested resource is not available.  i've stoped and restarted the server multiple times.

Can you help?

TIA,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.  New to BIRT.  Downloaded the latest one - 4.8.  After googling a bit, found out that 4.5 is compatible with tomcat 7.  I was able to deploy and run a sample report.